# reading Data on Oracle DB from Docker container

Tags: c#, oracle, docker, .net-core

My .Net Core application needs to read data from an Oracle DB. Here is my connection string:

```
"ConnectionString": "data source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=somehost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=somename)));user id=someuserid;password=somepass;Persist Security Info=true"
```

It works fine locally but once I deploy it to Docker it fails with this error (same user and pass):

```
ORA-12545: Network Transport: Unable to resolve connect hostname
```

Note that firewall is not the issue.

Comment: What exactly is deployed on docker?  Your App?  Oracle DB?  Both?

Comment: docker container exec -t client-container dig somehost ? This needs to resolve from within your client container